# Split String into 3 segments

Tags: javascript

I have a string in an array that looks like this:

```js
var x = ['100010004'];
```

And I have a variable named `y`, which is the splitted string of `x`.

How can I make that string into something like this:

```js
y = ['100-01-0004'];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change `["110010004"]` into `["110", "01", "0004"]`?

Comment: Did you try any of the [string methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)?

Comment: or do you mean x="110010004" into x="110-01-0004"?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to achieve - is it maybe just that you need masking?

There are several libraries out there that provide masking using specific patterns.

Comment: question updated. sorry, my bad

Comment: You may find `String.prototype.substring` or `RegExp` useful.

Comment: Let's include the real code in the question, please. `var x = [100010004]` is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: @jarmod Wait what's invalid about that?

Comment: Are you trying to do `'100010004'.match(/(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})/).slice(1).join('-')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could design a pattern like this:

```js
function SplitInto3Part(value, pattern) {
  var y = [],
    i = 0,
    x = value.toString();
  y.push(pattern.replace(/#/g, _ => x[i++]));
  return y;
}

console.log(SplitInto3Part([100010004], '###-##-####'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you always know the length of the strings, you can simply rebuild it appending the `-` where needed.

```
var str = "12345678";

console.log(str);

function replaceStr(str) {
  return str.slice(0,4) + '-' + str.slice(4);
}

console.log(replaceStr(str)); // prints "1234-5678"
```

Please note that in your example you are using an integer (a number) and javascript
will not accept a number with hiphens - you need a string for this type of manipulation.